# Какой нужен алгоритм, чтобы построить цепочку из нескольких слов? Например, шапка авто окно овал луза

Tags: c++, двусвязный-список

**В цепочке каждая последняя буква текущего слова должна совпадать с первой буквой следующего.**
Необходимо использовать *двунаправленный список*. Пробовал использовать перебор всех слов, но он работает долго и после 12 слов виснет. Сейчас пробую считать первые и последние буквы всех слов, чтобы предсказать, можно ли вообще составить цепочку. Но далее не понятно, как выбирать слова.

Comment: А критерий? Самая длинная цепочка, самая короткая?... Можно, например, сортировать для ускорения поиска, для кратчайшей цепочки - построить граф и поиск в ширину... Вот например, какой смысл в применении слово "окно"? :) Какую именно цепочку нужно построить?

Comment: Нужно использовать все слова. Как располагать слова - без разницы. Главное, чтобы была связь между словами.

Comment: Отсортировать в лексикографическом порядке?

Comment: Именно все? Тогда это [поиск гамильтонова пути](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8), NP-полная в общем случае задача. Есть, например, решение с помощью ДП за O(N^2*2^N).

Comment: А как тогда через двусвязный список реализовать?

Comment: Т.е. задача состоит в том, что на входе двусвязный список слов, надо из них построить список, в котором каждое слово начинается на букву, которой заканчивается предыдущее?

Comment: Да, именно в этом :)

Comment: Попробовать сначала расписать мультимножество начальных букв и конечных. Если они не равны, но отличаются только одним элементом в первом и одним во втором (или полностью совпадают) - шанс есть :)  Дальше выбираем в качестве первого слова то, которое начинается на эту несовпадающую букву, в качестве последнего - такое же, но с несовпадающей буквой в конце. А вот потом может быть всякое... Могут быть несвязные компоненты, например. Есть какое-то ограничение на количество слов?

Comment: "А вот потом может быть всякое" Я вот до этого и дошел)) Там 3 ситуации получается. 1) Начинаем с конкретного слова, заканчиваем любым из оставшихся 2) Заканчиваем конкретным словом 3) Начинаем и заканчиваем определенными словами. Ограничений нет. Вопрос в том, как организовать внутреннюю часть

Comment: Да, @MBO посмотрел на граф с другой стороны и он прав :) Я представлял граф, у которого вершины - слова, а он - ребра, и это сразу делает вашу задачу почти тривиальной :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это задача о [нахождении](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB) [эйлерова пути](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0) в графе.
Вот [здесь](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/euler_path) есть разбор задачи с домино - это практически то же самое (за исключением направленности)

Answer (score 0):

Признак такого предложения это - сумма первых букв и сумма последних букв должны совпадать, а допустимое расхождение 2 непристроенных символа.
пишешь первую проверку.
Если возможно, то далее цыкл: условие выхода в массиве осталось 0 слов.
Перебираешь слова, в случе если использовав слово "x" первым и количество букв оставшихся слов совпадает(с учетом, что для последней буквы слова х должна быть пара и конец предложения может остаться непарным) - добавляешь слово в предложение и убираешь его из анализируемого массива. Если после анализа последнего слова возможность не найдена - выводишь, что невозможно. Если цыкл отработал и не вывел отрицательного результата выводи переменную, в которую сбрасывал слова.
Количество цыклов для N слов = N*(N+1)/2 (для PC это небольшое количество)

```
//синтаксис не везде правильный, но алгоритм понятен и решает задачу
//arr - массив слов

function possible(arr){
 n=count(arr);
 for (i=0; i<n;i++){
  sum[substr(arr[i],0,1)]+=1;//ключ массива=первый символ 
  sum[substr(arr[i],-1)]-=1;//ключ массива=последний символ
 }
 k=0;
 foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
  if($value!=0)k++;
  if(k>2) return false;
 }
 return true;
}

possible(arr);
while(count(arr)==0){
 foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
  arr_bofer=$arr;
  unset(arr_bofer[$key]);
  success=false;
  if(possible(arr_bofer)){
     str.=arr_bofer[$key].' '; 
     unset(arr_bofer[$key]);//уменьшаем массив в случае успешной проверки
     success=true;//
     break;
  }
  if(success==false){//если цыкл прошел, но не нашел варианта
     print('невозможно');
  }
}
print(str);//вывод предложения
}
```